# Why is there no /etc/zsh.d/ in ubuntu, and where should I add system-wide options?

Tags: 16.04, environment-variables, zsh

I am trying to write an ansible role that needs to add to the `PATH`. For bash, I can easily add a file in `/etc/profile.d`. But zsh apparently doesn't come with an `/etc/zsh.d`. Is there another recommended method?

Note that I could obviously write to `.zshenv`, but this is possibly for many systems and I don't want to touch the system-installed files. Anything in `~/` is also unworkable, as I want to change `PATH` system-wide.

Answer (score 1):

The system-wide `zprofile` (`/etc/zsh/zprofile`) in Ubuntu contains:

```sh
# /etc/zsh/zprofile: system-wide .zprofile file for zsh(1).
#
# This file is sourced only for login shells (i.e. shells
# invoked with "-" as the first character of argv[0], and
# shells invoked with the -l flag.)
#
# Global Order: zshenv, zprofile, zshrc, zlogin

emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'
```

`/etc/profile`, in turn, sources `.sh` files in `/etc/profile.d` programmatically:

```sh
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

`/etc/profile.d` is not special in any other respect.

Additions to `PATH` you make in `/etc/profile.d` should affect zsh login shells. And for GUI users, LightDM sources `/etc/profile`, so any additions to `PATH` should be available to any program which doesn't reset it, including `zsh`.

IMO System-wide additions to `PATH` should be done using [`pam_env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/pam_env.8.html) (either in `/etc/environment` or `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, or custom files specified by an additional PAM rule).